# Why is Image.Save(Stream, ImageFormat) throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, icons, encoder

I am trying to convert an image to an icon. My function is:

```
private Icon GenerateIcon(int width, int height)
{
    using (Bitmap icon = _backingImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, System.IntPtr.Zero) as Bitmap)
    using(MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        icon.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
        return new Icon(imgStream);
    }
}
```

But when the programme calls the method, it throws an `ArgumentNullException("encoder")` where I'm calling `icon.Save`.

I find this odd because I'm not passing in an encoder, I want the framework to figure out what the encoder should be, which is why I'm passing in an `ImageFormat`.

Is it that there aren't any encoders for `ImageFormat.Icon`, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You guessed it right: GDI+ [only supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882579.aspx) an `ICON` *decoder*.

You might want to perform the conversion yourself. In that case, see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/safeicon.aspx.

Answer (score 5):

Just convert image to icon:

```
Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(((Bitmap)myImage).GetHicon())
```

and then save it using stream:

```
myIcon.Save(myStream);
```

regards,
Kate

Comment: Thanks, SmartK8. I am aware of that, however it doesn't work in partial trust scenarios.