# Image.Save() throws exception "Value cannot be null./r/nParameter name: encoder"

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am getting "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: encoder" error while saving a Bitmap image using RawFormat.
Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 400);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The RawFormat doesn't exist in the existing list of ImageEncoders as below code returns null.

`var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);`

Note: The image could be any type(JPEG, BMP, PNG) etc. Image.Save() should work on image.RawFormat.
RawFormat is not Bitmap type. If I Change image.RawFormat to ImageFormat.Bmp, the save operation succeeds.

Referred below links but found nothing for making it independent of image type.

[Image.Save crashing: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: encoder"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073619/image-save-crashing-value-cannot-be-null-r-nparameter-name-encoder)
[Why is Image.Save(Stream, ImageFormat) throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172112/why-is-image-savestream-imageformat-throwing-an-exception)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: it would be useful to include the stack trace?

Comment: Here is the stacktrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
   at CodeEval.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\temp\Program.cs:line 19
   
I have used bitmap just for representation, image could be of any type.

Answer (score 79):

If you load an image from disk, you can use `image.RawFormat` to save that image using its original format. However there is no encoder associated with an in-memory bitmap (which is what you are creating in this sample application), so you'll have to specify an image format yourself (ie. `ImageFormat.Bmp`).

Comment: Also, worth mentioning, an in-memory bitmap will have an image format of `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this and it will be fixed:

```
image.Save(stream,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```